# Add content to cell immediately after creating the sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am coding a VBA Script that:
1. Create some columns on one sheet
2. Create a new sheet
3. Add content to this new sheet

The issue is that as I run the script, everything goes fine but the content is not added to the new sheet. If I rerun the script, the content is added to the previously created sheet. How can I make it work from the first run?
Here is the script:

```
Sub AddColumn()
    'Declare variables
    Dim lastUsedRow As String
    Dim release As String


    'Get the number of current release
    release = ActiveSheet.Name

    'Get the number of the current Sheet

    'Affect values to variables
    lastUsedRow = CStr(last_Used_Row())

    'Write the column header
    Range("G1").Value = "Position"
    Range("H1").Value = "Requested"
    Range("I1").Value = "Planned"
    Range("J1").Value = "Delivered"
    Range("K1").Value = "Tested"
    Range("L1").Value = "Validated"

    'Formula for POSITION
    Range("G2:G" & lastUsedRow).Formula = "=LOOKUP(A:A,'Raw Data'!B:B,'Raw Data'!D:D)"

    'Formula for REQUESTED
    Range("H2:H" & lastUsedRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(R[0]C[-4]), ""NO"", ""YES"")"

    'Formula for PLANNED
    Range("I2:I" & lastUsedRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(R[0]C[-4]), ""NO"", ""YES"")"

    'Formula for DELIVERED
    Range("J2:J" & lastUsedRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(R[0]C[-4]), ""NO"", ""YES"")"

    'Formula for TESTED
    Range("K2:K" & lastUsedRow).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(OR(R[0]C[-1]=""NO"",AND(R[0]C[-1]=""YES"",OR(R[0]C[-4]=""40-To be tested"", R[0]C[-4]=""41-Pending retest"",R[0]C[-4]=""30-Fixed""))),""NO"",""YES"")"

    'Formula for VALIDATED
    Range("L2:L" & lastUsedRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(R[0]C[-2]=""YES"",R[0]C[-4]=""99-Closed""),""YES"",""NO"")"


    'Create the new sheet
        'Step 1: Tell Excel what to do if error
         On Error GoTo MyError
        'Step 2:  Add a sheet and name it
        Sheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Stats " & release
        Exit Sub
        'Step 3: If here, an error happened; tell the user
MyError:
        MsgBox "There is already a sheet called that."

    'Write on the sheet the row and column headers

    With Worksheets("Stats " & release)
        .Range("B7").Value = "S1-Blocking"
        .Range("B8").Value = "S2-Major"
        .Range("B9").Value = "S3-Medium"
        .Range("B10").Value = "S4-Minor"
        .Range("B11").Value = "Total"

        .Range("J7").Value = "S1-Blocking"
        .Range("J8").Value = "S2-Major"
        .Range("J9").Value = "S3-Medium"
        .Range("J10").Value = "S4-Minor"
        .Range("J11").Value = "Total"

        .Range("B13").Value = "S1-Blocking"
        .Range("B14").Value = "S2-Major"
        .Range("B15").Value = "S3-Medium"
        .Range("B16").Value = "S4-Minor"
        .Range("B17").Value = "Total"

        .Range("J13").Value = "S1-Blocking"
        .Range("J14").Value = "S2-Major"
        .Range("J15").Value = "S3-Medium"
        .Range("J16").Value = "S4-Minor"
        .Range("J17").Value = "Total"

        .Range("C6").Value = "Requested"
        .Range("D6").Value = "Planned"
        .Range("E6").Value = "Delivered"
        .Range("F6").Value = "Tested"
        .Range("G6").Value = "Working"

        .Range("K6").Value = "Requested"
        .Range("L6").Value = "Planned"
        .Range("M6").Value = "Delivered"
        .Range("N6").Value = "Tested"
        .Range("O6").Value = "Working"

        'Merge cells where needed
        .Range("A7:A11").Merge

        .Range("A13:A17").Merge
        '.Range("A13:A17").Value = "Other"
        .Range("I7:I11").Merge

        .Range("I13:I17").Merge
        '.Range("I13:I17").Value = "Other"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That's how you coded it.  You add a sheet, set its name and then Exit Sub terminates the method without adding any data.

Answer (score 2):

`Workbook_NewSheet` is the event needed. It should be in the `ThisWorkbook` class in VBE:

[image]

This would write "new content" in Range `A1:A5`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)

    With Sh
        .Range("A1:A5") = "new content"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If someone is willing to replace the screenshot with an English version of Excel, please feel free to do so.

Answer (score 1):

This section here:

```
'Create the new sheet
'Step 1: Tell Excel what to do if error
On Error GoTo MyError
'Step 2:  Add a sheet and name it
Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "Stats " & release
Exit Sub
```

Will always exit the sub unless there is an error. If you remove the `Exit Sub` it will work fine.

If you step through the code you will see what is happening, with the sheet already made it jumps over the exit sub, if the sheet is being created then it will exits. You may also want to check for the name before adding a new sheet so you aren't creating unnecessary sheets.